# Working with Windows 10 shortcuts

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

As you know in Windows 10 some so called "system apps" (such as Weather, Microsoft Edge and a dozen of others) use a different "path" to be executed. WSH methods in c# don't recognize it as path. Is there a way to fetch it via .NET framework 4+? Furthermore, location of these shortcuts in task bar and start menu original paths are hidden (unlike older Windows versions) and old ways to fetch them don't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe

This is the path for the Microsoft Edge Browser and is used for the Dreamweaver browser preview.